# Primefaces extensions warnings

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use CKEditor component from primefaces extension lib.
But when i adding this component and starting server i get warning:

*JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, ckeditor/ckeditor.js, from library, primefaces-extensions.*

The component should look like this:
[image]

But i am getting this:

[image]

What might be the reason of such behaviour ?

Comment: Is the resource available in the primefaces-extension library ? Else, try to change the version.

Comment: how can i check if the resource available in the primefaces-extension library ? :)

Comment: You did not mention the thrown exception ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I have to add one more maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
       <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
```